# Remove TimeZone from REST webservices in C#

Tags: c#, sql, rest

I am fetching Start Date and End Date from Database by following Query:

```
var contents = from u in entity.Submit_App
                       where u.EndDate >= currenteDate && u.StartDate < currenteDate
                       select new { u.App_Icon, u.App_ID, u.Actual_Price, u.App_Description, u.App_Title, u.EndDate,u.StartDate, u.iTunes_Link };
```

when checking the web services its gives the following output

```
"EndDate":"2013-09-28T19:30:00+05:30","StartDate":"2013-09-26T18:01:00+05:30"
```

I need to remove +5:30 in both start and End Date or Atleast Add "GMT" in front of +5:30

Comment: The date format seems to be correct according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), why would you want to change (and invalidate) it?

Comment: I need to give these web services to IOS team who developing this application.. they say they dont need that"+5:30" timezone.. yes web services is working accurately.. but they(IOS Team) insist they do no want that timezone there

Comment: So they want an incorrect date and time? Timezone isn't a cosmetic thing, it's real data. 09:00:00 in India and 09:00:00 in Germany are totally different moments in time. 23:00:00 in Germany would not even be the same DAY in India.

Comment: i sorted it my self nvoigt .. thnkx anyway 

used the query in following way

Comment: var contents = from u in entity.Submit_App
                           where u.EndDate >= currenteDate && u.StartDate < currenteDate
                           select new {appicon=u.App_Icon,appid=u.App_ID,appprice=u.Actual_Price,offprice=u.offerprice,appdes=u.App_Description,apptitle=u.App_Title,u.EndDate.Day,u.EndDate.Month,u.EndDate.Year,u.EndDate.Hour,u.EndDate.Minute,u.EndDate.Second ,startday=u.StartDate.Day,startmonth=u.StartDate.Month, startyear=u.StartDate.Year,starthour=u.StartDate.Hour,startmin=u.StartDate.Minute,startsec=u.StartDate.Second,itunes=u.iTunes_Link };